# Is there a size limit on attachments in CiviMail?

Tags: civimail

I am trying to attach a PDF of just 5024KB to a mailing in CiviMail. The attachment is failing, with no explanation as to why. Is there a file size limit or could anyone suggest another reason a file would not attach?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The maximum file size attachment can be set under  Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.). Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >>  Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.). Try after updating the maximum file size.
[image]
HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Please note that SMTP providers have their own limits

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at the  upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

SMTP providers have their own limits as to what attachments/file sizes they allow. For example - CiviSMTP (UAS) - has been max = 1MB for a long time. Not 100% if that has changed, but it makes sense that there are limits as to attachments to bulk email messages.